# Paho MQTT stops receiving and publishing messages after a day or two

Tags: python, multithreading, mqtt, paho

I have been having some interesting issues recently with Python and MQTT.

Basically, my code is subscribing to a topic, and every time there is a new message published, it tries to control a device. Now, this is a blocking function and thus is run in a separate thread, so that `on_message()` would return immediately.

Additionally, the code publishes a status to a topic every 60 seconds. The code runs fine in the beginning, often a day or two. The device is being controlled via subscribed MQTT messages and the status is published just fine.

Then, it suddenly stops receiving any MQTT messages and also stops publishing them. The `publish()` function however, does not indicate that there would be problems, and `is_connected()` returns `True`. Restarting the program allows it to run another day or two. Below is the full code.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
import threading
​
class Controller():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mqtt_client = mqtt.Client()
        self.pub_topic = "outgoing"
        self.mqtt_client.on_message = self.on_message
        self.mqtt_client.connect("192.168.1.1", 1883, 600)
        self.mqtt_client.subscribe("incoming")
​
    # This is a blocking function, execution takes approximately 5 minutes.
    # The function only runs if there is no existing thread running it yet.
    def control_device(self, input_commands):
        print("Do some stuff...")
​
    def process_mqtt(self, msg):
        mqtt_msg = json.loads(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
        self.control_device(mqtt_msg)
        payload = '{"message":  "process started"}'                                                                                                       
        self.mqtt_client.publish(self.pub_topic, payload)
​
    def on_message(self, client, userdata, msg):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.process_mqtt, args=(msg,))
        thread.start()
​
    # Status is sent to the same topic every 60 seconds
    def send_status_msg(self):
        if minute_passed:
            payload = '{"status": 0}'
            self.mqtt_client.publish(self.pub_topic, payload)        
​
    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.mqtt_client.loop()
            self.send_status_msg()
​
if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Controller()
    c.run()
```

Is there something I have not understood about how the MQTT library works? I found some discussion about how you should not publish inside `on_message()`, but in this case it is put into a separate thread.

Comment: I'd add `client.on_publish = on_publish` just to make sure the callback is called when the message is actually published. how is `minute_passed` set/reset?

Comment: Is the indent correct for `self.control_device(mqtt_msg)` in `def process_mqtt(self, msg):`?

Comment: @hardillb: The indentation is quite broken in a number of places. @ jiipeezz: could you please edit the question to correct the indentation?

Comment: @hardillb I can try adding that. Variable minute_passed is a simple comparison using time.time().

Comment: Also I don't know if this is relevant, but I found this thread mentioning that at least version 1.5.0 is not thread safe https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/issues/358. I use version 1.6.1 of the library, and at least seems like this could be the issue?